# How to merge dataframes and return the merged df from a function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am reading data from yahoo through a function. I have a list of stocks and end and start time defined. Then using the code below I am iterating through the list of stocks and storing each stock data seperately under name X+'StockName'. I think this part is working fine.

But then I want to generate a dataframe that merges all these single stock data and gives it as a result of the function. I am stuck there badly.

Can you plese help me out?

```
secs = ['UNH','XOM','HD','DIS','GE','USB','ORCL','KO','PEP','MMM']
DataCollector = ""

def DataCollection(secList,startTime,endTime):
    newList = []
    for i in range(len(secList)):
        DataCollector = 'X' + str(secList[i])
        print(DataCollector)
        newList.append(DataCollector)
        print(newList)
        DataCollector = pd.DataFrame(pdr.get_data_yahoo(secList[i], start = start, end = end)['Adj Close'])
    data = pd.concat(pd.Series(newList))
```

I have tried many ways and this is the last error I got for the code above.
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "Series"

Answer (score 0):

You need to just replace the last line of your function to

```
def DataCollection(secList,startTime,endTime):
    newList = []
    for i in range(len(secList)):
        DataCollector = 'X' + str(secList[i])
        DataCollector = pd.DataFrame(pdr.get_data_yahoo(secList[i], start = start, end = end)['Adj Close'])
        newList.append(DataCollector)
    return pd.concat(newList).reset_index
```

---

**Example**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def DataCollection():
    newList = []
    for _ in range(2):
        df = pd.DataFrame({"X" : np.random.randint(0,10,size=4), "Y" : list("abcd")})
        print(df)
        print("*" * 10)
        newList.append(df)
    return pd.concat(newList).reset_index()

print(DataCollection())
```

**Output**

```
   X  Y
0  9  a
1  4  b
2  7  c
3  6  d
**********
   X  Y
0  5  a
1  0  b
2  0  c
3  6  d
**********
   index  X  Y
0      0  9  a
1      1  4  b
2      2  7  c
3      3  6  d
4      0  5  a
5      1  0  b
6      2  0  c
7      3  6  d
```

Comment: Thank you abhilb but this time I am getting : TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid , kind of thing I have got before. newList is a list of strings and pd.concat doesn't get it. I think moving newList.append(DataCollector) to a place after DataCollector = pd... will work. Trying it now.

Comment: I have added an example for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

The code below solves the problem. creating newList after assigning DataCollector as dataframe.

```
def DataCollection(secList,startTime,endTime):
    newList = []
    for i in range(len(secList)):
        DataCollector = 'X' + str(secList[i])
        print(DataCollector)


        DataCollector = pd.DataFrame(pdr.get_data_yahoo(secList[i], start = start, end = end)['Adj Close'])
        newList.append(DataCollector)
    return pd.concat(newList)
```